# Dynamically render a bootstrap element in a template

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I want to dynamically render a bootstrap icon in my template based on the result of a function.

I tried something like this

```html
           <template>
               <div>
                    {{ getUsersEmaillRequestStatus(user.id) === EMAIL_STATUS.SUCCESS ? 
                     `<b-icon icon="check-circle"></b-icon>` 
                      : "something else" }}
               </div>
            </template>
```

And it just renders everything inside my double curly's.

I also tried to do something like this

```html
<div v-html="emailResultFunction() />
```

```js
emailResultFunction() {

     return `<b-icon icon="check-circle" style="color: #328dd1" font-scale="4"></b-icon>`
}
```

and it just doesn't work either. How do can I render an icon dynamically based on the result of a function?

I also tried to use just and svg and i couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`v-if`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-if) on the `<b-icon>` to conditionally render that component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-icon v-if="getUsersEmaillRequestStatus(user.id) === EMAIL_STATUS.SUCCESS"
            icon="check-circle"></b-icon>

    <div v-else>Something else...</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-conditionally-render-icon?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: lol, woof. of course. This is how you know you've been coding for too long and need to take a break. thank you for the answer.